# Weird animation when deleting item from UICollectionView while UIContextMenu is shown

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicontextmenuinteraction

I'm using `UIContextMenuInteraction` to show a context menu for `UICollectionView` as follows:

```swift
func collectiovnView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: { _ in
        let deleteAction = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), attributes: .destructive) { _ in
            self.deleteItem(at: indexPath)
        }
        return UIMenu(title: "Actions", children: [deleteAction])
    })
}

func deleteItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    })
}
```

Everything works well, but when I tap the "Delete" item, a weird animation happens where the deleted item stays in its place while other items are moving, and then it disappears instantly. And sometimes I even see an empty space or a random item for fraction of a second before the new item appears.

If I call `collectionView.deleteItems()` while the context menu isn't shown the deletion animation works as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the weird animation is a result of a conflict between two animations that run at almost the same time:

1. **Deletion animation**: When "Delete" item is tapped, `collectionView.deleteItems()` is called and the specified collection item is deleted with animation.
2. **Menu dismiss animation**: After the menu item is tapped, the context menu is also dismissed with another animation that shows the deleted item for a fraction of a second.

This looks like a bug that should be fixed by Apple. But as a workaround, I had to delay the deletion until the dismiss animation completed:

```swift
func deleteItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let delay = 0.4 // Seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.items.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        })
    }
}
```

The `0.4` seconds is the shortest delay that worked for me.

Comment: @robmathers Unfortunately, no.

Comment: 0.7 delay worked best for me...It sucks that we have to make workarounds like this but well, on to the next one I guess